# Tensorflow Callback: how to save best model on the memory not on the disk

Tags: python, tensorflow, callback

I use Tensorflow for regression using the following function

```
import tensorflow as tf

def ff(*args, **kwargs):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=[inp_train.shape[-1],]))
    for i in range(n_layer):
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_unit, activation=act))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(out_train.shape[1]))
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mae')
    early_stop  = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=100)
    check_point = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
    model.fit(inp_train, out_train, epochs=n_epoch, batch_size=s_batch, validation_data=(inp_val, out_val), callbacks=[early_stop, check_point], verbose=0)
    best_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('best_model.h5')
    return model, best_mode
```

As you see, I save the best model by `check_point` callback and use it later for prediction. The problem is that in this way I have to save the best model on the disk first, and then load it from the disk. If I want to do a couple of runs in parallel, since each run create a file with the same name it does not work.

So, how can I assign the best model in a variable without having to save it on the disk?

Comment: Write a simple ```MetricsCallback``` class that copies ```model``` to wherever you like

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman OK. How can I get the best model without saving it into the disk, then load it and copy it to wherever I like?

Comment: Check my updated comments below answers

Comment: Your are monitoring val_loss using EarlyStopping, so training ends with best model. Therefore just removing your checkpoint line of code and using my custom callback should work for you. If you're still not convinced, let me know and I will add monitoring val_loss in my custom callback, but there's no point really as EarlyStopping is doing that. My solution does what you asked for, ie. no saving of model and store in a 'variable'.

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman Thanks for the update. Actually, EarlyStopping does not end with best model if the patience is larger than 1. We can still restore the best model by restore_best_weights=True. This works however only if EarlyStopping is invoked. Have a look at this: [https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12511]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NOTE: I fixed a bug and is untested

I had to do this for myself and thought I would share:

Callback:

```
class SaveBestModel(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, save_best_metric='val_loss', this_max=False):
        self.save_best_metric = save_best_metric
        self.max = this_max
        if this_max:
            self.best = float('-inf')
        else:
            self.best = float('inf')

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        metric_value = logs[self.save_best_metric]
        if self.max:
            if metric_value > self.best:
                self.best = metric_value
                self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()

        else:
            if metric_value < self.best:
                self.best = metric_value
                self.best_weights= self.model.get_weights()
```

usage:

```
save_best_model = SaveBestModel()
model.fit(data, callbacks=[save_best_model]
#set best weigts
model.set_weights(save_best_model.best_weights)
```

Comment: thanks for this solution but for 100 epoch it doesnt work do u have any idea why ?

Comment: I just updated it but can't really test it right now. Let me know if it works any better

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example of creating a callback and saving the model at the time of callback to an external `list`. It has to be a list (or a type that allows modification using a method). The base `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` class is extended with an additional argument, the list, in the callback class `__init___` method. This example shows that it works. When the callback is called on `training_end` it appends the current model to the list.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model

# define a custom callback
class MyCustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

  def __init__(self, external_list):
      self.list_obj = external_list

  def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
      self.list_obj.append(self.model)

# test the idea works
model_save_list = []
my_callback = MyCustomCallback(model_save_list)

model1 = Model()
my_callback.set_model(model1)
my_callback.on_train_end()

print(model_save_list)
```

Run this and you will see the internal model gets added to your list object:

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x10d230b50>]
```

Modify your training by adding your new callback to the callbacks like so:

```
model.fit(inp_train, out_train, epochs=n_epoch, batch_size=s_batch, validation_data=(inp_val, out_val), callbacks=[early_stop, my_callback], verbose=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that it still uses the 'check_point', which saves the model on the disk. You see, tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckPoint creates a file named 'model_best.h5' on the hard disk. I want a workaround to not create this file on the hard disk, rather assign it to a variable.

Comment: Also the best model is not necessarily the last model. You see, I used the patience in the early stopping to go further. So, the best model is located way before the early stopping' last epoch.

Comment: My solution doesn't require checkpoint, it's a callback on training, but I take your point about last not necessarily best... I will work on that :)