# Using the configuraiton from the best epoch in keras without saving a file

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a keras model that I train and I save the configuration from the best epoch in a separate file and load it afterwards. Here is my whole code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dense, Flatten
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Read data from  csv files
ANN_input_data_features = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/TestDataANN_InputFeatures.csv", sep=';')
ANN_input_data_labels = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/TestDataANN_OutputLabels.csv", sep=';')
ANN_input_data_features = ANN_input_data_features.values
ANN_input_data_labels = ANN_input_data_labels.values

            
# standardize input features X and output labels Y
scaler_standardized_X = StandardScaler()
ANN_input_data_features = scaler_standardized_X.fit_transform(ANN_input_data_features)

scaler_standardized_Y = StandardScaler()
ANN_input_data_labels = scaler_standardized_Y.fit_transform(ANN_input_data_labels)


#Split dataset into train, validation, an test
index_X_Train_End = int(0.7 * len(ANN_input_data_features))
index_X_Validation_End = int(0.9 * len(ANN_input_data_features))

X_train = ANN_input_data_features [0: index_X_Train_End]
X_valid = ANN_input_data_features [index_X_Train_End: index_X_Validation_End]
X_test = ANN_input_data_features [index_X_Validation_End:]

Y_train = ANN_input_data_labels [0: index_X_Train_End]
Y_valid = ANN_input_data_labels [index_X_Train_End: index_X_Validation_End]
Y_test = ANN_input_data_labels [index_X_Validation_End:]


#Train the model
optimizer_adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate= 0.001)

numberOfInputFeatures = len(ANN_input_data_features[0])
numberOfOutputNeurons = len(ANN_input_data_labels[0])

model = keras.Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=(numberOfInputFeatures,)),
    Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    Dense(50, activation='relu'),
    Dense(50, activation='relu'),
    Dense(30, activation='relu'),

    keras.layers.Dense(numberOfOutputNeurons)])

#Important part 1: The file with the best configuration is saved
entireFolderNameForTheResultsOfTheRun = "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Training/"
pathOfTheFileForBestModel = entireFolderNameForTheResultsOfTheRun + "bestModelSingleTimeSlotTest.keras"
callbacks = [  keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(pathOfTheFileForBestModel,  save_best_only=True) ]

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=optimizer_adam, metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=2000, batch_size=10, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid), callbacks=callbacks)

# Predict the values from the test dataset
#Important part 2: The file with the best configuration is loaded
model = keras.models.load_model(pathOfTheFileForBestModel)
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

I indicated the important parts with comments (Important part 1 and Important part 2). Now my question is, whether I can also use the configuration of the best epoch for predictions without saving a file by just using the script? The motivation behind this is that the script will run on a plattform where I can't save any files.

Comment: Just save your models in memory instead of on the disk. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630990/tensorflow-callback-how-to-save-best-model-on-the-memory-not-on-the-disk

Comment: @AloneTogether: Thanks AloneTogether for the link.